# JavaScript method to remove case insensitive duplicates from string/Numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Looking for a clean way to remove duplicates and keep with the first occurrence of the duplicate number/letter found

Let’s say I have a string

AbCyTtaCc113

What I want remaining is

AbCyT13

Comment: I’ve tried something using filter() after splitting the string but best i can get is removal of duplicates but it’s case sensitive unfortunately (do not have code on phone will post later if required)

Answer (score 4):

```
  [...input].filter((s => c => !s.has(c.toLowerCase()) && s.add(c.toLowerCase()))(new Set)).join("")
```

Spreading a string results in an array with one character strings, by using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)  you can easily filter out duplicates. The logic is basically:

- Turn the string into an array of characters by spreading it (`[...input]`).
- Create a Set and store it inside of the closure as `s`. (`(s => ...)(new Set)`)
- Filter out the characters if

  - the character is in the Set already (`!s.has(c.toLowerCase())`
  - if it is not, add it to the Set and keep it (`&& s.add(c.toLowerCase())`)
- Turn the filtered array back into a string by joining it.

Or the case insensitive version:

```
[...new Set(input)].join("")
```

---

The imperative version would be:

```
  let result = "";
  {
     const duplicates = new Set();
     for(const char of input) {
        if(!duplicates.has(char.toLowerCase()) {
          duplicates.add(char.toLowerCase());
          result += char;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use `[...input]` to split a string into an array of one-character strings and not `.split("")`?

Comment: @stevendesu Why would you even consider using `input.split("")` if you can do `[...input]`?

Comment: @kevin no, I'm not that kind of answerer. Because I like the explicitness of turning something into an array. `[...stuff]` everyone sees that this is an array now.

Comment: @connexo Because not all interpreters support the spread operator (namely NodeJS) and because the semantic of the spread operator are not as well understood by newbie developers

Comment: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) have an extra argument you can use as `this` inside it. You can use it to pass a `new Set()` instead of using the closure, but you will have to avoid the arrow function expression for the filter callback.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't need ES6, it does not make it faster, nor cleaner for this case. Walk it once and reduce:

```
"AbCyTtaCc113"
.split("")
.reduce((ac,d)=>{!~ac.toLowerCase().indexOf(d.toLowerCase()) && (ac += d); return ac;},"")
```

Comment: Note: quadratic time complexity due to `indexOf`.

Comment: Yes it is O(n^2), I'd really wonder if it would make any difference with string length of 50 average. 0.01ms?

Comment: You realize that arrow functions are ES6 ?

Comment: @JonasWilms, indeed. I cheated to make the expression 8 letters shorter :)

Answer (score -1):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` would be one way to address this.

**Edit:** As others have mentioned, there's valid reasons though not to use this for production level solutions. So just take it as one *possible*, though not *advisable* way.

```js
console.log(
  [..."AbCyTtaCc113"]
    .reduce(
      (acc, val) => 
        acc.includes(val.toUpperCase()) || acc.includes(val.toLowerCase())
          ? acc 
          : [...acc, val]
        , []
    )
    .join("")
)
```

Comment: Reducers are not the way to go, as this is not a reduction problem. If he wanted to find something like "the most common letter" then that would technically be a reduction problem (reducing a set of multiple letters to a single letter), albeit on that's actually hard to implement with reducers since they operate with little memory of the total state of the system.

Comment: You *do* reduce the Array to a single value - the string consisting only of the required letters.

Comment: Why reassign `acc` just to return it then?

Comment: @connexo Are you perceiving the string as an array of letters, or as a single entity? Because in the former case, you've performed a filter (mapping an array of letters to a smaller array consisting of a subset of those same letters). In the latter case, you've performed a transformation (mapping a single value to a different single value). In neither case did you perform a reduction. You only reduce if in one instance you interpret the string as an array and in another you interpret it as a primitive.

Comment: Just remove the `{ return ... }` ?

Comment: By the way, a big problem that hasn't been mentioned with this answer is it takes a linear operation and makes it quadratic by virtue of the `.includes` operation. Use a set or object for O(1) lookup to preserve O(n) overall time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

I believe @ggorlen has the appropriate solution, although he uses some rather modern JavaScript (I haven't seen a syntax before using back-ticks instead of parenthesis to call functions, but I'll trust it works in some interpreters)

For a simpler "old-school" answer, try something like the following:

```
var input = "AbCyTtaCc113";
var output = "";
var unique = {};
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (!unique[input[i].toLowerCase()]) {
        unique[input[i].toLowerCase()] = 1;
        output += input[i];
    }
}
```

### Second update

The ES6 solution below was preserved for historical purposes, but @ggorlen pointed out that I failed to preserve casing on the output. Therefore the conversion to lowercase should only occur within the filter check and not prior:

```
var input = "AbCyTtaCc113";
var seen = new Set();
var output = input
    .split("")
    .filter(x => !seen.has(x.toLowerCase()) && seen.add(x.toLowerCase()))
    .join("")
```

### Update

Since everyone is having fun writing ES6 answers and trying to solve this with `reduce` or `map` or `Set` or some other such tool, let me write what I think is the ***best*** answer using ES6:

```
var input = "AbCyTtaCc113";
var seen = new Set();
var output = input
    .split("")
    .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
    .filter(x => !seen.has(x) && seen.add(x))
    .join("")
```

Or, if you prefer unreadable one-line nonsense:

```
var input = "AbCyTtaCc113";

var seen = new Set(), output = input.split("").map(x => x.toLowerCase()).filter(x => !seen.has(x) && seen.add(x)).join("");
```

I prefer this solution because:

1. It utilizes method chaining to pass our input through a series of simple transforms which can be easily read and interpreted by future programmers (first split, then map, then filter, then join)
2. It avoids syntax that isn't supported in many JavaScript interpreters (no spread operators, back-ticks, etc)
3. It uses each method for its semantic purpose (split converts a string to an array, map modifies each value of an array, filter selects a subset of an array, join converts an array to a string)

That said, if performance is your primary concern and you're running this in the Google Chrome console, I must admit that preliminary benchmarks peg Jonas Wilm's answer as faster than mine:

```
var d0 = new Date(); for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    var input = "AbCyTtaCc113";
    var output = [...input].filter((s => c => !s.has(c.toLowerCase()) && s.add(c.toLowerCase()))(new Set)).join("");
} console.log(new Date() - d0);
// ~175

var d0 = new Date(); for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    var input = "AbCyTtaCc113";
    var seen = new Set();
    var output = input
        .split("")
        .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
        .filter(x => !seen.has(x) && seen.add(x))
        .join("");
} console.log(new Date() - d0);
// ~231
```

I believe this is because `.map()` is allocating a new array in memory rather than modifying the array in-place (whereas his solution utilizing `.toLowerCase()` within `.has()` modifies the values in place so uses no extra memory), but I prefer this for clarity. Unless you're dealing with code where performance is of the utmost importance, I think being able to read the code is more important than eeking out an extra millisecond.

Comment: Btw, these are missused tagged template literals, so yes, thats valid ES6

Comment: Who is bored enough that they're going around giving a -1 to every single answer posted in this question? Every answer can be verified correct.

Comment: @stevendesu they haven't all received a -1

Comment: @KevinB You're right, only Jonas Wilms hasn't. I guess he's the culprit :D (just kidding, who know who the culprit it, to the best of my knowledge votes on SO are anonymous and if they're not I'd rather remain ignorant)

Comment: @stevendesu Pretty sure the downvoter is protesting the fact that a number of people answered a question that didn't include an attempt at solving it.

Comment: Your second version doesn't preserve casing on the output.